# Quasiconcavity of $g(x)=xf(K-x)$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, game-theory, economics

The function $f(x)$ is strictly increasing, finite, positive and twice continuously differentiable on the compact interval $[0,K]$, and $f(0)=0$.

I'm trying to either find a counterexample to, or a proof of the fact that, for such $f(x)$, the function:

$$g(x) = x f(K-x)$$

is quasiconcave.  A few tools/observations I've made along the way:

- If two functions on the same domain are positive, quasiconcave and co-monotone, then their product is quasiconcave
- If two functions are co-monotone and quasiconcave, then their sum is quasiconcave.
- $g(x)$ always has precisely two zeros on $[0,K]$: one at 0 and the other at $K$, and is strictly positive on the interior.

I've tried both the usual proof using quasiconcavity definitions as well as plugged in a large variety of test functions for $f(x)$, and all give me a quasiconcave $g(x)$.  If someone can give me a counter-example or any advice on proving a positive result, it would be great!

Comment: Why does $g(x)$ have a zero at $K$? It looks like $g(K)=Kf(0)$, and both $K$ and $f(0)$ are positive.

Comment: @MichaelGrant you're right, sorry, I had been playing with functions that $f(0)=0$.  For the type of problem this is for, that turns out to be without loss of generality.  I've updated the main post to reflect this!